# Get statistics for certain period

Tags: mysql

I have table Audience:
id(int), unixtime(int), country(int), city(int), audience(int).

The appointment of the table - keeping statistics for some abstract audiences for different cities and countries. Statistics are collected several times a day, at different times for different cities and countries.

Need help in composing query, which should show the audience for each cross country and city

1. for the first and last date
2. for a certain period of dates

Output should contain

- country1, city1, unixtime, audience - min(unixtime)
- country1, city1, unixtime, audience - max(unixtime)
- country1, city2, unixtime, audience - min(unixtime)
- country1, city2, unixtime, audience - max(unixtime)
- ...

or:

- country1, city1, begin_unixtime, begin_audience, end_unixtime, end_audience
- country1, city2, begin_unixtime, begin_audience, end_unixtime, end_audience
- ...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT b.country,
       b.city,
       b.unixtime AS begin_unixtime,
       b.audience AS begin_audience,
       c.unixtime AS end_unixtime,
       c.audience AS end_audience       
FROM   (
       SELECT   MIN(id) AS minid,
                MAX(id) AS maxid
       FROM     audience
       WHERE    unixtime BETWEEN <start> AND <end>
       GROUP BY country,
                city
       ) a
JOIN   audience b ON b.id = a.minid
JOIN   audience c ON c.id = a.maxid
```

---

In this solution, the min/max unixtime and audience are based on the min/max `id` (first and last row inserted between specified dates), assuming it's a unique auto-incrementing int.

Replace `<start>` and `<end>` with your date range.